# Select all elements except ... in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working on a project, what includes a smartsearch engine.

I'd like to write a method what makes the client write inside the smartsearch, even when it's not focused. F.e. browsing the site, the client **hits down a key**, and the **focus** jumps to the smartsearch.

That's working fine with this simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
 $("*").keydown( function()
 { 
   $("input.ss-24#b").focus();
 });
});
```

But, yeah as You can see, it **unfocuses** other **inputs** too, and that's not the way I want it.
I have tried several 'possible-solutions', like **:not()** and even **.not()** method like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
 $("*").not("input").keydown( function()
 { 
  $("input.ss-24#b").focus();
 });
});
```

But it **still** unfocuses fields with "input" tagname too. What should I do to force jQuery **not** to select **input fields** for this event listener?

Thanks, Steven.

Comment: your input elements are within other elements, such as `<body>` and `<html>` which will be triggered on bubbling events.

Comment: I have a gut feeling that `$(document).keydown(function () { $('#b').focus(); })` should suffice.

Comment: Yes, Brian, You are right.
And I am pretty sure the problem is related to this point, @zzzzBov .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function() {
        if (!$('input').filter(':focus').length) {

             $('#b').focus();

        }    
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYEXB/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    $("input.ss-24#b").focus();
    });
});
```

Does this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/Xbbu8/

Comment: Sure, thanks, but how would it be a solution for the problem?

Comment: he probably forgot to add e.stopPropagation or immediatePropagation :)